# How to redraw TableViewCell when text of TextView on the cell is changed

Tags: ios, uitextview, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has TextView. And the cell height is changed by the text length of TextView by AutoLayout.
The cell has setter for the text(comment) and when calling the setter, the text of TextView on the cell is changed. But, when input long text than the before one, the TextView height does not change and the cell height also does not change. So, the cell can not show the new full text. Before calling setter, I also change data source. So, after scrolling and hiding the cell, by redisplaying the cell the cell has new TextView height which can show the new full text.

So, I think that if I can redraw the cell when changing the text, the cell shows new rect and the problem is nothing.

I tried `[cell  setNeedsLayout]` and `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]`.
But, could not redraw the cell.

CustomCell.h

```
@interface CustomCell :UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *comment;

@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
@interface CustomCell ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *commentTextView;

@end

@implementation CustomCell

- (void)setComment:(NSString *)comment {
    _comment = [comment copy];
    self.commentTextView.text = _comment;
    [self.commentTextView sizeToFit];
}

@end
```

If anyone know performing force redraw, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

**Set height constraint of your textView. When you set text of your textView, calculate height and set it again.**

```
/* set  textView text and height  */

textView.text = @"";  // your text here
CGSize sizeThatFitsTextView = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];
textViewHeightConstraint.constant = sizeThatFitsTextView.height;


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Thank you answer. By calculating TextView show the right height. But, cell height does not change. So, layout is broken. Do you know the way to adjust cell height?